# Bluetooth not working on my windows 11, what might be the problem?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, window, driver, settings

Bluetooth is not working on my windows 11, I’ve tried everything still.

Tried updating drivers and all but still. What might be the problem? Do I have to reinstall my windows? I need Ideas on what to do. Really confused on why it’s still not working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Your question does not fit here since it is not programming related. Maybe the [SuperUser StackExchange](https://superuser.com/) site is better suited